# Get specific words from a string in python

Tags: python

I want to to extract some information from a data file. The following is the format I have in my data file:

```
44 2.463181s> (G) GET_NBI: 0x00002aaa ecc00e90 <- (4,0x00002aab 4c000c00) (256 bytes)
```

From this line, I want to extract 256 which is the last number and 4 which is the first number from

```
(4,0x00002aab 4c000c00)
```

Could you please recommend some functions which will be useful for my case?

Comment: um, python comes with excellent string splitting methods. Also, regular expressions might be your fried.

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; what have *you tried*, and what's the problem with your attempt?

Comment: *Please* try to do your own research, especially on the documentation at least a little bit before asking here.

Comment: @JamesLu you have somewhat undercut that message by giving them an answer...

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ I love fried regex!

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's true, although this *is* a question-and-answer site...

Comment: @skrrgwasme :D that might have slipped my mental orthography check. I'm ducking fense at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `str.split()`.

What it does is split the string every place there is a space, so you would get a list of strings like so:

```
n = '44 2.463181s> (G) GET_NBI: 0x00002aaa ecc00e90 <- (4,0x00002aab 4c000c00) (256 bytes)'
o = n.split() 
print o
```

Output:

```
['44', '2.463181s>', '(G)', 'GET_NBI:', '0x00002aaa', 'ecc00e90', '<-', '(4,0x00002aab', '4c000c00)', '(256', 'bytes)']
```

Then simply get the second-to-last index like `o[-2] -> '(256'`

Remove the extra parenthesis: `'(256'[1:] -> '256'`, and If you wanna, turn it into an integer. `int('256') -> 256`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use regular expressions, which in this case might be a bit more clear.

```
import re

txt = "44 2.463181s> (G) GET_NBI: 0x00002aaa ecc00e90 <- (4,0x00002aab 4c000c00) (256 bytes)"

results = re.findall(r"\((\d+)", txt)
# ["4", "256"]
```